# Unable to get flask app running on 127.0.0.1

Tags: python, flask, vagrant, virtualbox

I am trying to incorporate a Google sign in button on my site. However, Google OAuth client does not allow requests from host http://0.0.0.0:someport. When I attempt to change my host to http://127.0.0.1:someport my server starts and runs but the site cannot be reached. I am running a Linux server using vagrant and virtual box. No error is outputted via terminal(Mac) and changing the port does not resolve the issue.

**Starting My Server**

```
app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = 'super_secret_key'
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it can not be reached because you didn't route the page you want to reach (and also hopefully you installed the framework flask and didn't forget to import the class Flask from flask).

Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Hello World"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = 'super_secret_key'
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000)
```

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = 'super_secret_key'
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```